# Command line way to know the cycles (phases) of the moon

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

I'd like a simple way to know when the next fullmoon is, and would prefer not to rely on a web service. I don't want a GUI since I'd like to call this from a script.

Thanks all!

Comment: There is a post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2531541/2907484) pointing to a Python script [there](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~keturn/py-moon-phase/trunk/annotate/head:/moon.py) which does not work on Linux (the module `datetime` is spelled `DateTime` and more...) but I suppose our python masters here can fix it in a second... and the other answers give several otions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this python [script](http://inamidst.com/code/moonphase.py) which seems to base its calculation  on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_phase#Calculating_phase.

```
$ python moonphase.py
Full Moon (0.503)
```

Comment: To make it work with Python 3, add parentheses to the `print` command on line 40: `print( "%s (%s)" % (phasename, roundedpos) )`

Answer (score 0):

Try [pom](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man6/pom.6.html), from the [bsdgames](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/bsdgames) package:

`sudo apt install bsdgames`

Or [this Perl script](https://metacpan.org/dist/PerlPowerTools/view/bin/pom) also named `pom`.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu and thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour].  Please read [answer] and learn how to craft high quality answers by reviewing how mivk has modified your post.